# How to move references just one cell if I drag the formula six rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I have a formula that references to `$K4`. When I copypaste this formula six rows below, I want to get `$K5`, instead of `$K10`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

This should work for you. 
1. In the formula bar highlight the formula
2. Press Control C
3. Click on the cell you want the formula in
4. Click on the formula bar and press Ctrl & V

You might need to change 4 to 5. You could drag the formula to the cell below to get $K5 first, the do all the above from there, but it is likely more work.

Hope this helps,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

1. At the location of the 1st `$K4` formula.. `=INT(ROW()/6)` || What answer did you get? say x .
2. use indirect to build "replacement" formula : so replace the `$K4` with `=INDIRECT("K"&((INT(ROW()/6)-x)+4),TRUE)` .. where x is number you get from step 1.
3. do this for every different formula that use `$K4`.
4. Then you may drag the 'new' formula as usual.

Have a try. (and share if it works/or not) (: